# sharethis is stopping page to load in IE 8

Tags: sharethis

I have a sharethis link on my site having the below mentioned code ...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       addthis_url = location.href;
       addthis_title = document.title;
   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/addthis_widget.php?v=12"></script>
```

But this is not working as the page stops loading after the addthis_widget.php like . I even changed the code to newer version i.e.

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN --> <a class="addthis_button"></a> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js?pub=ogmios"></script> <!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

But this code is too stopping the page load in IE8.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Jawed

Answer (score 0):

Jawed,

Looks like you are using AddThis not ShareThis..

Why don't you try using ShareThis instead http://sharethis.com/publishers/get-sharing-tools

-Manu

Comment: Thanks for the reply Manu, and sorry for mistake, I am using sharethis.